# Инициализация атрибутов базовых классов при множественном наследовании

Tags: python, классы, наследование

Не могу разобраться до конца в классах Python. Задаю объекты:

```
p1 = Point(50,70)   # объект класса Point, задающий начальную координату
c1 = Color(10,15,10)   # задает цвет
r1 = Rectangle(p1,40,70,c1)   #в нем и загвоздка, а точнее в p1 и c1
```

Как сделать так, чтобы r1 имел также аргументы x и y и r,g,b, которые имеют p1 и c1 соответственно.

!!! в моем классе Rectangle `self.pointIn = pointIn` и `self.color = color` явно заданы неправильно

```
 class Point(object):
        def __init__(self,x=0, y=0):  
            self.x = x
            self.y = y

        def modify_point(self, x1,y1):
            self.x = x1
            self.y = y1

        def to_tuple(self):
            return (self.x, self.y)

    class Color(object):
        def __init__(self,r=0, g=0, b=0):  
            self.r = r
            self.g = g
            self.b = b

        def to_tuple(self):
            return (self.r, self.g, self.b)

    class Rectangle(Point, Color):
        def __init__(self, pointIn, width, hight, color):        
            self.width = width
            self.hight = hight
            self.pointIn = pointIn
            self.color = color
```

Comment: Во первых, вам не нужно наследовать Rectangle от Point и Color (это как минимум не логично). Вы и так передаете их объекты конструктору (т.е. используете композицию) и можете получить доступ к их свойствам. И не совсем понятна суть вопроса. Вы хотите что бы класс Rectange тоже имел свойства  x, y и r,g,b? Зачем, если к этим свойствам вы можете достучаться через полученные объекты: self.pointIn.x, self.pointIn.y и self.color.r, self.color.g, self.color.b.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прямоугольник может *иметь* цвет. Прямоугольник сам по себе цветом *не является*. То есть логичнее использовать: `rectangle.color.r` вместо `rectangle.r` и не наследовать от `Color` (тем более вы уже используете композицию: `self.color` определён).

> Как сделать так, чтобы r1 имел также аргументы x и y и r,g,b, которые имеют p1 и c1 соответственно.

Если забыть, что это прямоугольники, точки, цвета и рассматривать задачу как упражнение по использованию множественного наследования (которое следует избегать, если вы не знаете точно зачем оно вам нужно в конкретном случае), то *чтобы правильно проинициализировать унаследованные атрибуты базовых классов, необходимо вызывать `super().__init__(**kwargs)`*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3   

class A:    
    def __init__(self, a, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.a = a

    def __repr__(self):
        keys = sorted(self.__dict__)
        items = ("{}={!r}".format(k, self.__dict__[k]) for k in keys)
        return "{}({})".format(type(self).__name__, ", ".join(items))

class B:    
    def __init__(self, b,  **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.b = b

class C(A, B):    
    def __init__(self, c, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.c = c

print(C(a=1, b=2, c=3))
```

`super().__init__()` вызов только один в `C.__init__()`, не смотря на то что C имеет два базовых класса.

`A.__init__()` и `B.__init__()` *существуют* и также *вызывают* `super().__init__()` и все эти методы имеют *совместимые* аргументы (за счёт `**kwargs`). См. [Python’s super() considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

[`__repr__` метод (с реализацией из документации `types.SimpleNamespace`)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) определён, чтобы напечатать C объект. Вывод показывает, что все атрибуты правильно установлены.

Ключевое понятие здесь—порядок разрешения методов (MRO)—порядок, в котором вызываются методы базовых классов:

```
>>> [klass.__name__ for klass in C.mro()]
['C', 'A', 'B', 'object']
```

`С.__init__` ожидаемо вызывает родительский `A.__init__` (через `super().__init__()`). `A` класс не наследует от `B`, но `A.__init__` вызывает (через `super().__init__()`) `B.__init__` согласно MRO, который вызывает `object.__init__` и цепочка заканчивается.

`object` встречается в этом списке только один раз, хотя он является базовым классом как для `A` так и `B` классов (то есть `C` наследует от `object` класса дважды). Чтобы вычислить порядок вызовов, в Питоне используется [C3-линеаризация суперкласса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Comment: спасибо за объяснение! не пойму только, указание базового класса object является обязательным или это дэфолтное значение? и как поменяется функциональность кода если вместо class A  написать class A(object)?

Comment: @NatashaLazovskaya: код работает как есть (python3 shebang). На Питоне 2, следовало бы в этом случае добавить явно `A(object)` и в `super()` вызов дополнительные аргументы пришлось бы передать. Если интересует разница на Питоне 2, то задайте отдельный вопрос.