# при создании объекта подкласса Building вылезает ошибка AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_Building__material'

Tags: python, ооп

Начинаю изучать ООП в Python 
Создал класc Buildings, подклассc Market в котором наследовал все атрибуты из Buildings.
Пробую создать объект подкласса но вылезает ошибка

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_Building__material'

```
class Building:
def __init__(self, material, color, number=0):
    self.__material = material
    self.__color = color
    self._number = number
    self.place(number)

def place(self, number):
    if self._number <= 0:
        print("Out of stock")
    elif (self._number > 0) and (self._number < 100):
        print("Placed in Warehouse")
    else:
        print("Remote warehouse")

def get_material(self):
    return self.__material

def set_material(self, material):
    self.__material = material

def get_color(self):
    return self.__color

def set_color(self, color):
    self.__color = color

def get_number(self):
    return self._number

def set_number(self, number):
    self._number = number

material = property(get_material, set_material)
color = property(get_color, set_color)
number = property(get_number, set_number)

def plus(self, quantity):
    self._number += quantity
    self.place(self._number)
    print("Added {} things of material".format(quantity))

def minus(self, quantity):
    self._number = self._number - quantity
    self.place(self._number)
    print("Removed {} things of material".format(quantity))

def __str__(self):
    return 'Building:\n\tmaterial: {}\n\tcolor: {}\n\tnumber: {}\n'\
           .format(self.__material, self.__color, self._number)


class Market(Building): 
def __init__(self, material, color, number=0, price=0):
    Building.__init__(material, color, number)
    self._price = price

def get_price(self):
    return self._price

def set_price(self, price):
    self._price = price

price = property(get_price, set_price)

def plus(self, quantity):
    super()._number += quantity
    super().place(super()._number)
    print("Added {} things of material".format(quantity))



bricks_market = Market("bricks", "orange", 120, 200)
```

Answer (score 1):

Первый аргумент у метода это `self`, а вы передаёте `material` строку в `Building.__init__`. [Используйте `super().__init__(**kwargs)` вместо этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/591493/23044).

Answer (score 0):

Замените строку:

```
Building.__init__(material, color, number)
```

на эту:

```
Building.__init__(self, material, color, number)
```