# Наследование в Python3: AttributeError: 'Atom' object has no attribute '_Base__setProperties'

Tags: python, python-3.x, наследование, множественное-наследование

Есть простой базовый класс Base:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__setProperties = dict()
        self.__setProperties['className'] = 'Base'

    def updateProperty(self, propertyName, propertyValue):
        self.__setProperties[propertyName] = propertyValue
```

Когда наследуюсь от QWidget и от Base вот так

```
class MainWidget(QWidget, Base):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.__setProperties = dict()
        self.updateProperty('className', 'MainWidget')
```

экземпляр класса MainWidget создать получается. Когда же наследуюсь просто от класса Base вот так:

```
class Atom(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__setProperties = dict()
        self.updateProperty('className', 'Atom')
```

при попытке создания экземпляра класса Atom возникает ошибка:

```
AttributeError: 'Atom' object has no attribute '_Base__setProperties'
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём дело.

**UPD**:
Если сделать так (поменять порядок QWidget, Base на Base, QWidget):

```
class MainWidget(Base, QWidget):
```

То возникает ошибка:

```
AttributeError: 'MainWidget' object has no attribute '_Base__setProperties'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имена начинающиеся на `__` являются частными для класса. Метод `Base.updateProperty()` использует `__setProperties` атрибут, который не определён при вызове из Atom класса (базовый `__init__` не вызван).

В варианте с `QWidget.__init__(self)` не было ошибки, так это метод неявно `Base.__init__()` вызвал (следуя `MainWidget.mro()`).

Если при наследовании использовать Base, QWidget порядок классов, то QWidget станет идти после Base in `MainWidget.mro()`, поэтому `QWidget.__init__(self)` в этом случае не вызывает `Base.__init__()` и снова `AttributeError` возникает.

Пример, демонстрирующий порядок вызовов:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class A:
    def __init__(self, a, **kwargs):
        print('A', a)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class B:
    def __init__(self, b, **kwargs):
        print('B', b)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class D(B, A):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


C(a=1, b=2)
D(a=10, b=20)
```

Результат:

```
A 1
B 2
B 20
A 10
```

Один вызов `super().__init__(**kwargs)` в `С` привёл к вызову `A.__init__()`, `B.__init__()` и в обратном порядке для `D`. В зависимости от цепочки наследования `A.__init__` может вызвать `B.__init__` и наоборот. Это зависит от  `C.mro()` и `D.mro()`:

```
print(C.mro())
print(D.mro())
```

Результат:

```
[<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>]
[<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>]
```

Связанный вопрос: [Классы, наследование, атрибуты в python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/591362/23044)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и уточнение! Благодаря ему я разобрался.